# How to remove characters in a VB.NET string

Tags: vb.net, string

I have a VB.NET string and I only need a portion of it.
The string's structure is similar to this:

```
RANDOM DATA 123456 ---BEGIN--- part I need of the string ---END--- RANDOM DATA 123456
```

I only know that before the part I need, there's "---BEGIN---" and after there's "---END---"

How can I cut off everything and only keep "part I need of the string"? It's important to cut also ---BEGIN--- and ---END---

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Regular Expressions approach.  Note that it will find all occurrences if there is more than one set in your data.  I've modified your example string to demonstrate this:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim raw As String = "RANDOM DATA 123456 ---BEGIN--- part I need of the string ---END--- RANDOM DATA 123456" & _
            "RANDOM DATA 123456 ---BEGIN--- another part I want ---END--- RANDOM DATA 123456" & _
            "RANDOM DATA 123456 ---BEGIN--- more stuff I want ---END--- RANDOM DATA 123456"


        Dim pattern As String = "---BEGIN---(.*?)---END---"
        For Each G As Match In Regex.Matches(raw, pattern)
            Dim data As String = G.Groups(1).Value
            Debug.Print(data)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IndexOf to find the location of the Begin and End strings and SubString to extract the part you need.

```
Dim myString As String = "RANDOM DATA 123456 ---BEGIN--- part I need of the string ---END--- RANDOM DATA 123456"
Dim startPos As Integer = myString.IndexOf("---BEGIN---")
Dim endPos As Integer = myString.IndexOf("---END---")
Dim shortString As String = myString.SubString(startPos + 11, endPos - startPos - 11)
```

If it is possible that the string doesn't contain both the begin and end strings, you should check whether startPos or endPos is less than 0 (meaning "not found")